# preg_split разбить теги img

Tags: php, строки

Доброго времени! Простоя задача но я не силен пока в составлении регулярок, прошу помощи.

есть строка с тегами img

```
$str = "<img src='image1.jpg'>   <img src='image23.jpg'><img src='image3.jpg'>";
```

Надо разбить ее в массив переменных использую как разделитьель это > < начало одного тега и конец другого, при этом надо учесть что между > и < может быть рандомное количество пробелов или вообще не одного (а может и табуляция)
пробовал так и сяк вот например:

```
$seal = preg_split("/>.+?</",$str);
```

но у меня из строки где всего 3 тега img мои вариации выдают безумные результаты когда проверяю результат через count
то 1 то 62 то 70 и пр. но реального значения получить не могу

Comment: А в чём суть задачи, что нужно получить? Парсить html регулярными выражениями не очень хорошая идея, лучше использовать domDocument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preg_match_all('/<.+?>/', $str, $result);
$seal = $result[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю вам вариант не разделения, а выборки (захвата в массив) всех тегов :

```
preg_match_all('~(<img src=\'[a-z0-9\.]+\'>)~u', $str, $matches);
```

Результат смотрите в $matches[1]:

```
print_r($matches[1]);
```